# How to add / delete reference to class pointer to/from a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, delete-operator

The class setup is a bit strange, but it is what it is. I have a problem when I attempt to delete a pointer to a class instance given the following classes:

```
class Foo {
    Foo() { x = 5; }
    ~Foo() {}
    int x;
}

class Bar : public Foo {
    Bar() {}
    ~Bar() {}
    void Test() { std::cout << "Hello World! " << x << std::endl; }
}

class Base {
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}

    vector<Foo*> vec;
    void Add(Foo* const &f) { vec.push_back(f); }
    void Delete() { 
        delete vec[0];
        vec[0] = NULL;
        vec.clear();
    }
}

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() { b = new Bar(); }
    ~Derived() {}
    AddBar() { Add(b); }
    Test() { b->Test(); }

    Bar* b;
}
```

Basically, `Derived` has a `Bar pointer` that is dynamically allocated at some point, and is then later passed into an `std::vector of Foo pointers`, from which `Bar` is derived. The `vector` is maintained in a class that `Derived` inherits from and the `vector` is used to perform a whole bunch of different actions with all the elements in the `vector`, but for now I'm showing a single entry.

The problem lies when I try to delete an element from the `vector`, like below:

```
int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.Test();    // works fine, outputs: "Hello World! 5"

    d.AddFoo();
    d.Test();    // works fine, outputs: "Hello World! 5"

    d.Delete();
    d.Test();    // doesn't work fine, outputs: "Hellow World! -17891602
}
```

The memory is freed, seeing how the integer is now garbage data, but d still thinks its `Bar*` exists, even after deleting it and setting it to `NULL` in `Base.Delete()`.

**Is there a way** to have the local `Bar*` in `d` be freed/deleted and set to `NULL` without having to do it from the `Derived` instance itself ( i.e. have the program crash when it attempts to do the final `d.Test()` class )**?**

Technically, I can do that as it is, but it feels messy and inefficient.

Also, if there is a decent answer that doesn't resort to smart or unique pointers, I'd personally prefer that and I'm not going to debate about why.

If that's the only solution, I'm all for it.

**Edit:** Messed up with Derived::b when I first wrote it, fixed now

Comment: `f = new Foo();` What is `f`?

Comment: `Derived::b` appears to be uninitialised based on your posted code.

Comment: *"I'd personally prefer that and I'm not going to debate about why"* That's why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Well the obvious solution is to store a `Foo**` in that vector. But I'd argue that breaks the design even more. It looks a bit like a `shared_ptr` plus `weak_ptr`, though that could be reduced to a custom solution since there seems to be only one owner.

Comment: So what all of this boils down to is this? `int main() { char *p = new char; char *q = p; delete q;  q = 0; }`?  And you want to have `p` set itself to 0 when `q` is set to 0?  Sorry, C++ doesn't work that way.  The p and q are separate variables -- setting one variable to a value doesn't set the other.

Comment: Since you need to notify other objects of the change in vector, maybe utilizing a design pattern such as Observer would be a better solution, along with usage of smart pointers.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem that you're trying to solve, but you have some UB because your subclass destructors are not virtual. To fix this, follow this rule: every destructor **must** be exactly one of: `virtual`, `protected`, `final`.